# Godaddy fails to properly configure NTP on their node server hosting my VPS

Tags: centos, vps, ntp, godaddy, ntpdate

I have a few VPS servers with Godaddy and with every new server I contracted I had to ask them to set up NTP on the node hosting my container. They always did until now.

It seems like their technicians don't have a clue when it comes to time synchronization and keep talking about changing time zones.

On a VPS you can't set up NTP as it uses the system clock of the main machine running the VPS so of course I don't have access to that. I can choose my time zone but that's it. Since the system clock is going off more and more every day (1.5 seconds/day) I'll be having problems soon. I already called in like 5 times and sent numerous support tickets but no luck so far.

Does anyone have experience with system clocks on Godaddy VPS servers? Can I do something, what do I need to ask them?

Comment: What sort of VPS is it? Most Virtualization software offers the ability to uncouple from the parent, xen has `xen.independent_wallclock = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` which will then make reference to your ntp server.. not dom0.

Comment: After reading up on ways to figure out what my server is on I can conclude it's OpenVZ

Comment: Hmm, the exception to the rule.. http://serverfault.com/questions/446289/changing-time-or-offsetting-it-in-openvz-contained-server, basically, get your host to change the time, or tell him you're taking your business elsewhere.